# C stack usage 7970960 is too close to the limit

Tags: r, exponential

I tried to compute a simple exponential function in RStudio as,

```
> exp(1)
```

And I received following error message:

> Error: C stack usage  7970960 is too close to the limit

Now I can't run any exponential computing in RStudio anymore but last night it was all good! I tried to do it in regular R and it works. So weird. I tried to expand the limit in terminal (I am using Mac) but that seems not to stay permanent..

What happens to computation? Does anyone know how to remove this error?

Comment: I can run " exp(1) " in regular R (not R studio) but it doesn't work in R studio.

Comment: what are the results of `find("exp")` in RStudio?

Comment: RStudio is just an IDE, i.e. a fancy script editor. There's absolutely no way that you would get different behaviour in the R console vs. through RStudio.

Comment: Yes, but the OP could be working with different environments, one of which contains the bogus recursive function and the other of which does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly have a bogus function called `exp` in your search path somewhere, which calls itself.  It may be in your workspace (global environment), or (less likely but possible) in a package you have loaded. (It's also possible that the *infinite recursion* is defined in a more complicated way, i.e. rather than `exp()` calling itself, it calls something that calls it back ...)

The normal, expected result of `find("exp")` is

> [1] "package:base"

Suppose you have defined a recursive `exp` function in your workspace:

```
exp <- function(x) exp(x)
```

Then `exp(1)` will give

> Error: C stack usage  7969716 is too close to the limit

and `find("exp")` will give

> [1] ".GlobalEnv"   "package:base"

i.e. there is an `exp` in the global environment that R will see before it sees the built-in function in the `base` package.

If you do have something like this going on, starting a new R session will help (unless the object is in a saved workspace that gets restored when the session starts), or `rm("exp")`.