# Error: C stack usage when compile R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I get a new error, when I try to compile an R Markdown file int appears the next message:

```
Error: C stack usage  7971408 is too close to the limit
Execution halted
```

I did some research and I found some people with the same error:

- [Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719349/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit)
- [C stack usage 7970960 is too close to the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64687333/c-stack-usage-7970960-is-too-close-to-the-limit)
- [GenomicRanges: C stack usage ... is too close to the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225966/genomicranges-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit?rq=1)
- [R mapping (C stack usage 7971616 is too close to the limit)](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-mapping-c-stack-usage-7971616-is-too-close-to-the-limit/60267/2)
- [C stack usage 7972356 is too close to the limit #335](https://github.com/broadinstitute/infercnv/issues/335)

But these guys have problems with some function or something like that.
The actions I did in orden to try to solve this situation:

- Uninstall R and RStudio, reinstall de last versions of both, reboot my computer... nothing.
- Try to change `ulimit -s`, and this point is interesting because this is my `ulimit -a` on R terminal:

```
geomicrobio-mac:~ geomicrobio$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 10240
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1392
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

When I try to change de `ulimit -s` for `unlimited` or `65532` on R terminal, it doesn't change.

The `ulimit -a` of my terminal (macOS Monterey v12.0.1) is:

```
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             65532
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-u: processes                       1392
-n: file descriptors                2560
```

This just happen with R Markdown, I can do Shinny apps, and run scripts, etc. but I can`t compile any R Markdown despite it contains only text.

This is the info when I put `base::Cstack_info()` on console:

```
      size    current  direction eval_depth 
   7969177      14032          1          2
```

My version of R:

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin17.0     
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin17.0                  
system         x86_64, darwin17.0          
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2021                        
month          11                          
day            01                          
svn rev        81115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
nickname       Bird Hippie
```

If you know how to solve this I really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: i clicked on only a few of those questions and as i suspected all were some kind of infinite recursion or user error. there is an rmarkdown log tab in rstudio, have you looked through that and isolated the code chunk that is causing this error? have you resolved your previous question about knitr?

Comment: No, I haven't :c

Comment: There isn't code, because it happens with any R markdown file. Also with the file which just contains text.

Comment: do you have anything in your .rprofile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just delete the .Rprofile .-.